# jQuery / Dynatree: How to use Json or ul/li together with IFrame sample

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm a newbie with dynatree, but happy that i've found this supercool plugin.

On the dynatree site, I've found an example how to use it with IFrames
http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-iframe.html

I was able to adapt the IFrame example successfully. But i'm a bit
stuck here, because I'd like to load the tree either via UL/LI or
better, with Jason/Ajax. my problem now is, that I dont understand how
to provide ther url/links with LI or Jason, so that clicking an entry still opens the linked site in the iframe. Also don't know how I have to format parents/children/subchildren in Json..

Would anybody be so kind to give a sample with iframe and jason/ajax
or iframe with ul/li?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest using the JavaScript object syntax rather than the UL/LI style, because it's more performant (drawback: the UL markup would be rendered, even if JavaScript is disabled).

The trick is, to simply add a custom attribute to the node data (in this example we may call it 'url') like so:
`{title: "Google", url: "http://www.google.com"}`

Then, in the activation handler, access this attribute like this: `dtnode.data.url`.

Excerpt from the sample page ( http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-iframe.html ):

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
      onActivate: function(dtnode) {
        // Use our custom attribute to load the new target content:
        if( dtnode.data.url )
          $("[name=contentFrame]").attr("src", dtnode.data.url);
      },
      children: [
        {title: "Search engines", isFolder: true, expand: true,
          children: [
            {title: "Google", url: "http://www.google.com"},
            {title: "Yahoo", url: "http://yahoo.com"}
          ]
        },
        {title: "jQuery", isFolder: true, expand: true,
          children: [
            {title: "jQuery", url: "http://www.jquery.com"},
            {title: "jQuery UI", url: "http://ui.jquery.com"},
            {title: "API browser", url: "http://api.jquery.com"},
            {title: "dynatree", url: "http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    });
```

If you want to use an Ajax request, to receive this data from a server in JSON format, 
this sample - written in Python - may give a direction:

```
# Build node list as JSON formatted string:
res = "["
res += "{ 'title': 'Node 1', 'key': 'k1', 'isLazy': true, 'url': 'http://foo.com' },"
res += "{ 'title': 'Node 2', 'key': 'k2', 'isLazy': true, 'url': 'http://bar.com' }"
res += "]"

# Add support for the JSONP protocol:
# This means, if the request URL contains an argument '?callback=xxx',
# wrap the result as 'xxx(result)'
if "callback" in argDict:
    res = argDict["callback"] + "(" + res + ")"

# Make sure, content type is JSON:
start_response("200 OK", [("Content-Type", "application/json")])

# Return result (the square brackets are Python / WSGI specific):
return [ res ]
```

Note that in Ajax/JSON mode you don't have to return hierarchical structures. Instead, you may mark the nodes `lazy`, so another request is sent when the nodes are expanded for the first time.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and time mar10 :-) Was finally able to got it running. Took me a bit to find out how to do the subfolders:

[
   {
      "title":"Simple node",
      "key":"1"
   },
   {
      "title":"Folder 1 ",
      "isFolder":true,
   "url": "http://www.ggerri.com",
      "children":[
         {
            "title":"Simple node11",
   "children":[
   {
    "title":"Simple node111",
    "key":"3"
   }
   ]   
         },
         {
            "title":"Simple node12",
   "url": "http://jquery.com"
         }   
 ]
   },......

Thanks again and take care :-)
G

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to got it running. Took me a bit to find out how to do the subfolders in json:

```
    [
       {
          "title":"Simple node",
          "key":"1"
       },
       {
          "title":"Folder 1 ",
          "isFolder":true,
          "url": "http://www.ggerri.com",
          "children":[
             {
                "title":"Simple node11",
                "children":[
                {
                    "title":"Simple node111",
                    "key":"3"
                }
                ]           
             },
             {
                "title":"Simple node12",
                "url": "http://jquery.com"
             }    
        ]
       },
       {
          "title":"Folder 2",
          "isFolder":true,
          "url": "http://www.ggerri.com",
          "children":[
....
```